# Why is my ADO Access connection is giving different results than the same query run in Access application?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've been trying to figure this out for over a day and I feel like the answer comes down to how Access handles data types, but I still haven't figured it out.  I've simplified the issue in the hopes that it will be easier to solve.  I have 2 columns in an Excel workbook - Column A is Text, and Column B is dates.  Basically I just want to select the dates from Column B when Column A is not null.  This works fine in theory but not for actual situations I'm running into.

Ex: Instead of Column B being all dates, one of the values for column B is just a null string.  To handle this, I simply added an IIF statement that if column B is `=''` make it 0:

```
querystr = "Select IIF([Enroll Date] = '',0,[Enroll Date]) As vdate FROM [Sheet1$] where [Account Number] IS NOT NULL"
```

This query works perfectly fine when I import the worksheet to Access, but when I use it with an ADO connection for Excel VBA, all records come back as `Empty`, except for the zero length string which comes back as null.  This sub will set up the entire workbook for you and demonstrate the entire thing:

```
Sub flow()

Dim con As Object
Dim rec As Object
Dim path As String
Dim y As Integer: y = 1
Dim sht1 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = ActiveSheet

path = SetData()

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties=" & Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES" & Chr(34) & ";"


con.Open

    querystr = "Select IIF([Enroll Date] = '',0,[Enroll Date]) As vdate FROM [Sheet1$] where [Account Number] IS NOT NULL"

rec.Open querystr, con

Range("D2").CopyFromRecordset rec
'every record is blank
rec.Close
rec.Open querystr, con

Do Until rec.EOF
    y = y + 1
    If IsEmpty(rec.Fields("vdate")) Then
        Range("G" & y).Value = "Empty"
    ElseIf IsNull(rec.Fields("vdate")) Then
        Range("G" & y).Value = "Null"
    End If
    rec.movenext
Loop

End Sub

Function SetData() As String

Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    With sht1
        .Columns.Item("A").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Columns.Item("B").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Range("A1").Value = "Account Number"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Enroll Date"
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
        For x = 1 To 5
            .Range("A" & x + 1).Value = x
        Next x
        Union(.Range("B2:B4"), .Range("B6")).Value = DateSerial(2016, 4, 1)
        'change B5 to accounting format
        .Range("B5").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        .Range("B5").Value = vbNullString
    End With


    With ThisWorkbook
        .Save
        SetData = .FullName
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: I would like that to convert any zero length strings to 0.  The reason is because the excel worksheet is downloaded from another application which leaves ranges that appear blank to actually be zero-length strings

Comment: What if you change `[Enroll Date] = ''` to `IsNull([Enroll Date]` in your `IIF` statement?

Comment: That does seem to fix it and is good to know, although I'm really wondering more about the root cause of the inconsistencies between the same query from Access compared to ADO Access so I can prevent issues like this in the future.

Comment: Great. Glad it worked. I made it an answer below, and the reason is because of how to work with data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[Enroll Date] = ''` to `IsNull([Enroll Date])` in your `IIF` statement.

In this instance, I suspect that `[Enroll Date]` is formatted in Access as `Date` and `Date` data types cannot have a value of `''` (or empty string). It's either a valid date or null.

That said, when transferring data between Access and Excel, you have to get the data types spot on in each system for it to work properly. I can't give you a decent explanation, here, but if you google for it, you can find plenty of things discussing data type issues when transferring data from Excel to Access.

Comment: I do actually have another question about this though, because if I add an `OR` statement, it gets even more confusing.  Changing `IIF([Enroll Date] = ''` to `IIF([Enroll Date] IS NULL OR [Enroll Date] = ''` causes every record EXCEPT the null string to come out empty.  The null string correctly comes out as 0 as expected

Comment: Removing the `OR` statement altogether yields the correct result completely.  Very confusing

Comment: Your syntax is wrong `=IIF(IsNull([Enroll Date] or [Enroll Date] = ''`

Comment: I changed the syntax, though both are giving the same result

Comment: It may be converting it for you into the right syntax when you pass it, since it's close. Please mark as answered, if it works for you, so others will be aware that this question was solved.